# Trying to run 2 macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run these two macros, I know the first one works, and according to the internet the second will work too.  I believe I have the first macro calling the second like I should.  I get a "Compile error: Argument not optional"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    If Not Intersect(Range("j2:o1000,r2:aa1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rng In Intersect(Range("j2:o1000,r2:aa1000"), Target)
            rng.Value = UCase(rng.Value)
        Next rng
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    Worksheet_SelectionChange
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Range("H1").Sort Key1:=Range("H2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Comment: both macros are **Events** that run automatically and you should therefore not run them manually as this causes a lot of weird things. They are intended to run **only** automatically: `Worksheet_Change` gets triggered whenever a value in a cell changes. and `Worksheet_SelectionChange` gets triggered whenever you select another cell. • Note that sorting whenever you click and select another cell is a very bad idea, as the worksheet will be almost unusable because it sorts all the time you click somewhere. • Re-think your approach. [Edit] and describe what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Ok what i am trying to achieve with the first macro is that if there are all Xs or N/As in a bunch of cells, then the entire row turns off the highlighting.  If any of the necessary steps are not done, then highlight entire row.  The second macro, I am trying to automatically update the rows base on the H column which is a date.  I currently am manually sorting by the H column, every time i add a row of information.  Looking for a way to automate it.

Comment: Your description does not match your code at all. I see nothing in your code that handles `X` or - `N/A` nor does it handle any highlighting. Please read [mcve] provide proper example input data and a good description of what goes wrong. And show what you expect as result.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, what i mentioned above, is done via conditional formatting.  Sorry first macro was copied from the internet to use only use uppercase in the cells that would have the X or N/A that i mentioned previously.  The second macro is supposed to the sorting I mentioned above.  So what i am looking for from the above macros, is to have all text in cells J2 through O1000 be changed to uppercase if they aren't already.  And then to update automatically via the date in column H.  Does this answer your questions?

Comment: I got it to work, thanks for the help.